# Is there a ready way to which of multiple screens the active window is on?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, desktop

I am trying to find which screen from the Screen.AllScreen array of Screen objects contains the active window, so I can use that one to show a new window.

The best way I can think of is to pinvoke to get the foreground active window, then somehow find some kind of screen position from that object, then compare that point to the array of screen object areas to see if it is contained there.  The top left corner would be good enough, and I am going to ignore the possibility of an active window showing on multiple monitors simultaneously.

Is there a simpler way that would avoid pinvoke's getforegroundwindow and the contained point iteration search?

Comment: Do you have access to the `Active form` without using GetForegroundWindow? I guess the active form may belong to another application?

Comment: Yes, the active form might be in another application or process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the static method `Screen.FromHandle()` to get the screen containing the largest portion of the active form (by `Handle`) like this:

```
Screen scr = Screen.FromHandle(GetForegroundWindow());
```

There are 3 more static methods which get `Screen` from `Control`, `Point` and `Rectangle`.